# Outlook 2010 not storing settings; Customize Ribbon is empty

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

(Windows 7 64-bit, Office 2010 32-bit, a lot of free HDD space).

I had my Outlook 2010 set up according to my habits and it worked for years, but a couple of weeks ago some of the settings have started being reset on each application start. I change them every day, but the next day or the next reboot they have their default values again.

- The "Favorites" pane on the left is opened. I hide it, next time it appears again.
- The To-Do Bar on the right is opened. I hide it via the View tab, next time it appears again.
- When I create a new mail message or reply to a message, the font is default "Calibri", for reply it has an ugly bluish color. I change the font and color in Options > Mail > Stationery and fonts, next time it's Calibri again.
- When I open a message and click Reply in the message window, a reply message window appears and the original message remains open. I click the Options > Mail > Replies and forwads > Close original message checkbox, next time it's unchecked again.

Also, my custom ribbon tab has disappeared. In Options > Customize Ribbon, all lists and drop-downs are empty, so I can't display or create it again.

Interestingly, some other settings are being stored correctly:

- My custom signatures are alive and are being correctly inserted into each message. Now I use them to copy my desired font.
- The customized columns (e.g. I'm displaying the "From" column in "Sent Items") are kept.
- My custom VBScript macros are stored (they should be called from my custom ribbon tab).

What can I do to make the settings work again? It seems like Outlook is unable to store part of the settings, probably some folder has become read-only, but which one? I could reinstall Office, but if something is corrupt on the machine or in the registry, the issue is likely to appear again. And I don't want to format and reinstall the whole system...

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: @DavidPostill, tried it right now, rebooted the computer, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Outlook 2010 not storing settings**
>
> I had my Outlook 2010 set up according to my habits and it worked for
>   years, but **a couple of weeks ago** some of the settings have started
>   being reset on each application start. I change them every day, but
>   the next day or the next reboot they have their default values again.

This sounds like the issue with a Microsoft Update (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114409) released on December 8, 2015 that causes Outlook to start in Safe Mode. See below for all further detail related to this issue and potential fixes—be sure to read everything.

---

### THE PROBLEM EXPLAINED WITH MULTIPLE SOLUTIONS

*(You should apply the fix as per the Microsoft recommendation in this instance though)*
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
(**Resource Link:** *http://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-starts-safe-mode/*)

---

### THE MICROSOFT RECOMMENDED FIX

Go here --> *https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114560*, download the applicable update for your version of Outlook 2010, read over the entire article, and then install per the instructions.

Comment: Thank you! I installed KB3114560 and all my old settings appeared without having to set them up from scratch. (Except my custom ribbon tabs; probably I have lost them while trying to reset everything. But the Customize Ribbon functionality also became available so I created the custom tabs again).